# Want to retrieve the full Path of URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading the pictures to a file server and I want to retrieve the full Path with the URL.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Uploads/OnlineLoanApplication/"));
if (!dir.Exists)
{
    dir.Create();
}
string fileName = onlineLoanApplication.BVN + onlineLoanApplication.Firstname + onlineLoanApplication.Surname;


string filePath = "/Images/Uploads/OnlineLoanApplication/" + fileName + ".jpg";

img_Passport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
```

Now it saves properly in the format below:

```
/Images/Uploads/OnlineLoanApplication/Filename.
```

But I want to have another field where by i can have the full path that contains the Domain name as well such as:

```
www.uthumvc.com/Images/Uploads/OnlineLoanApplication/Filename
```

Comment: Does this help? `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`

Comment: The above concantenated with the URl I have already?

Comment: Yes, `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` should return the 'host' part of the url.

Comment: Alright, Let me try it Out

Comment: It works well. Thank you. Can you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` to return the 'host' part of the url, then concat accordingly to your needs.